# Django double User check

Tags: python, django, admin

I’m aiming to establish a warehouse inventory manage system. Now I want to achieve that, when warehouse manager give the material to the worker for producing, I want the warehouse manager create a record(name, time, and manager name and so on) first, and then worker log in to his/her own site and check the record then confirm it. Which achieve double check.

Is there any way to achieve it.
Thank you for help.

Comment: set a status field for the record, default value is pending when created by manager and update it to done after confirmed by worker

Comment: You could also have 2 fields `manager_approved` and `worker_approved` that store 1 or 0